# LINQ Record to Datagrid using Foreach string Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, datagridview

```
private void getPOP30300(string rr) 
{

    try
    {
        DBSFCDataContext SFC = new DBSFCDataContext();
        var query = (from i in SFC.POP30300s 
                     where i.POPRCTNM == rr 
                     select new { RRno = i.POPRCTNM, Rdate = i.receiptdate, 
                       GLSPOST = i.GLPOSTDT, VENDID = i.VENDORID, 
                       VENDNAME = i.VENDNAME, SUBT = i.SUBTOTAL, PYMT = i.PYMTRMID,
                       Ddate = i.DUEDATE, PSEDDTT = i.POSTEDDT, PTDURID = i.PTDUSRID,
                       USER2 = i.USER2ENT, CREATDDT = i.CREATDDT, MODIFDT = i.MODIFDT,
                       TRXSORCE = i.TRXSORCE, ORSUBTOT = i.ORSUBTOT, 
                       DEXROWID = i.DEX_ROW_ID, REMARKS = i.REMARKS, 
                       TRCKSCALRECIPNO = i.TRUCK_SCALERECEIPTNO, TRCKFEE = i.TRUCKFEE,
                       UNLFEE = i.UNLOADFEE, PRNTCOST = i.IsPrintCost, 
                       TRCKNO = i.TRUCKNO, QTYSHIPBAGS = i.Qtyshippedbags, GW = i.GW,
                       TAREW = i.TAREW, NETWT = i.NETWT, PKGWT = i.PKGWT, 
                       PLATENO = i.PLATENO, VPNUM = i.VPNum, VPDATE = i.VPDate,
                       AMNTNWORDS = i.AmountInWords, VPRMKS = i.REMARKS, 
                       VPPOST = i.VPPost, VPEXPRT = i.VPExport });

        foreach (var r in query)
        {

            //DGVpop30300.DataSource = r;

            string[] row = { r.RRno.Trim(), r.Rdate.ToString(), r.GLSPOST.ToString(),
                             r.VENDID.ToString(), r.VENDNAME.Trim(),
                             r.SUBT.ToString(), r.PYMT.ToString(), r.Ddate.ToString(),
                             r.PSEDDTT.ToString(), r.PTDURID.Trim(), r.USER2.Trim(), 
                             r.CREATDDT.ToString(), r.MODIFDT.ToString(),
                             r.TRXSORCE.ToString(), r.ORSUBTOT.ToString(),
                             r.DEXROWID.ToString(), r.REMARKS.Trim(), 
                             r.TRCKSCALRECIPNO.ToString(), r.TRCKFEE.ToString(),
                             r.UNLFEE.ToString(), r.PRNTCOST.ToString(),
                             r.TRCKNO.ToString(), r.QTYSHIPBAGS.ToString(),
                             r.GW.ToString(), r.TAREW.ToString(), r.NETWT.ToString(), 
                             r.PKGWT.ToString(), string.Format("{0:###-###0}", r.PLATENO), 
                             string.Format("{0:##-####0}", r.VPNUM),
                             r.VPDATE.ToString(), string.Format("{0:###,###.##0}", r.AMNTNWORDS), 
                             r.VPRMKS.ToString(), r.VPPOST.ToString(),
                             r.VPEXPRT.ToString() };

            { DGVpop30300.Rows.Add(row); }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}

private void getPOP30310(string rr) 
{

    try
    {
        DBSFCDataContext SFC = new DBSFCDataContext();

        var query = (from i in SFC.POP30310s 
                     where i.POPRCTNM == rr 
                     select new { 
                       RRno = i.POPRCTNM, RCPTLNNM = i.RCPTLNNM, POno = i.PONUMBER,
                       ITEMno = i.ITEMNMBR, ITEMdesc = i.ITEMDESC, 
                       VNDITNUM = i.VNDITNUM, VNDITDSC = i.VNDITDSC, 
                       UMQTYINB = i.UMQTYINB, ACTLSHIP = i.ACTLSHIP, UOFM = i.UOFM,
                       UNITCST = i.UNITCOST, EXTDCST = i.EXTDCOST, 
                       LOCNCODE = i.LOCNCODE, TRXSRCE = i.TRXSORCE, 
                       JOBNUMBR = i.JOBNUMBR, COSTCODE = i.COSTCODE, 
                       COSTTYPE = i.COSTTYPE, ORNUNTCST = i.ORUNTCST, 
                       OREXTCST = i.OREXTCST, ODECPLCU = i.ODECPLCU, 
                       BOLPRONUM = i.BOLPRONUMBER, ITEMrr = i.ITEMRR, 
                       DESC = i.DESCRIPTIONRR, PYMTRMID = i.PymtrMID, 
                       WHSArea = i.WHSArea, ISCHANGE = i.IsChangeExtendedCost });

        foreach (var r in query)
        {
            string[] row = { r.RRno.Trim() };
            { DGVpop30310.Rows.Add(row); }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

This above are the codes i have done.. now the 1st Function Works Perfectly But the Second One POP30310.. Does Not Display Any I dont know Why?? Please Help.. they look exactly the same already and i comment out the 1st function just to check if it work on the second still it doesn't display any of the data im trying to display...

Comment: You need to try stepping through the code to see where you have data and where you don't. Could be that SFC.POP30310s contains no data, or no POPRCTNM == r or r.RRno.Trim() returns and empty string? I recommend trying LinqPad to help debug queries. But also you can just break it down into chunks and keep adding until you find the bit where it goes wrong.

Comment: Does POP30310s have data that contains i.POPRCTNM == rr

Comment: Yes it have.. and i don't know why i try to place one data to retrieve and it doesn't all it show in the datagrid is an empty cell when i check on the databas it has a data.. is there datagrid properties i left unlock or does the parameter i used makes it an error i just repeat some of the parameter but i tried to comment the 1st function out to check if the 2nd really works without the 1st still it doesn't show any data?? i don't know why

Comment: Depending on what you are using to develop with you should be able to use debugger to step through the query. In this case you can use a breakpoint in the foreach statement to see if it is actually adding rows and then what the rows actually contain. Try this and let us know what you get...